# unexpected token import when use localize-router in Angular 4 Universal app

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, ngx-translate

I try to build Angular 4 app with server rendering side and language route path. All this base on Angular CLI in 1.5.0-rc1 version.

Everything work OK but I can't solve a problem with language in route.
I have two idea - one to make it like a parameter :lang in URL, but everywhere people advice me to use localize-router plugin. It look very good, but my `npm run server` can't start properly. In console I get an error:

```
/home/xxx/Projects/private/angular4-cli-seed/node_modules/localize-router/src/localize-router.config.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Inject, OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';
```

Here is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule, PLATFORM_ID, Inject, OpaqueToken} from '@angular/core';
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {LocalizeParser, LocalizeRouterModule, LocalizeRouterSettings, ManualParserLoader} from 'localize-router';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  }
];

export function localizeFactory(translate: TranslateService, location: Location, settings: LocalizeRouterSettings): LocalizeParser {

  const browserLocalizeLoader = new ManualParserLoader(translate, location, settings, ['en', 'pl'], 'pl');

  return browserLocalizeLoader;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    LocalizeRouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      parser: {
        provide: LocalizeParser,
        useFactory: (localizeFactory),
        deps: [TranslateService, Location, LocalizeRouterSettings, HttpClient]
      }
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  private static TranslateService: any;
}
```

Do you have any tips how can I solve it? I found some tips for Webpack (to use exclude list), but I want to use CLI because I don't know Webpack too well.

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200

Comment: Thanks. I analyze this well-develop github issue, and I think that only one solution is to recompile localize-router library. I write to the author with this problem, but probably it's impossible to get this in short time, so I should recompile this library oneself. Can you give any tips "How can I start with recompile process?"

Comment: No ideas, sorry. Don't use CLI myself.

Comment: Ok - i found a solutions. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is connected with library type - it's not a commonjs type, but ES6. More about this problem you can read [here on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200).

To solve it you can contact the author of library what you want to use in Angular 4 Universal (with Angular CLI). They should recompile it in a proper way.

Another solution (more quick to realize) give me a @sjogren on GitHub. You can use babel.js to recompile library during a building process. To do this you should run:

```
npm install babel-cli --save
npm install babel-preset-env --save
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save
```

and add this code in `package.json`:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
```

Finally in `package.json` you should add to your scripts prestart script with code to recompile the library. In my example:

```
"scripts": {
   "prestart": "node node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js node_modules/localize-router --out-dir node_modules/localize-router --presets es2015"
   "start": "......"
}
```

This worked fine for me, and I don't have an `Unexpected Token Import` error.